# Akka event bus with typed actor

Tags: java, scala, akka

I´m looking in google without success. Anybody knows if it´s possible use Akka Event bus to subscribe and send events to typed actors?.

And if you wonder, yes typed actors are mandatory :(

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should work out of the box. I've just had to provide typed ActorRef which supports given Event type.

```
class OTACTypedResponseEventBus() extends EventBus with LookupClassification{
    override type Event = ...
    override type Classifier = ....
    override type Subscriber = akka.actor.typed.ActorRef[Event]
```

Hope this helps.